# How speed up NIntegrate and plotting

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I studied all themes on Mathematica.StackExchange (for example most "famous" theme is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-nintegrate), but my example is more complicated one and none of the proposed methods don't work. My minimal example is as follow.

I start with solving an equation:

```
eqn = j - Sqrt[q^2 + qp^2 - 2*q*qp*Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
         Sqrt[qp^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
                  Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
                      4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*qp^2)])] == 0; 
With[{gensol = Solve[eqn, qp]}, 
     Block[{m = 5.5, M = 300, Nc = 3, 
         c = ScientificForm[-44687.3983417778], 
         b = ScientificForm[161593.81818181818], 
         k1 = ScientificForm[16.485010961790245], 
         k2 = ScientificForm[-13.131344420001051], ma, mp, j}, 
       {j = Sqrt[q^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 + 
                     Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
                         4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*q^2)])], 
          ma = Sqrt[-2*(M^2 - 2*(3*k1 + k2)*
                     (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
                          m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))^2 - c + 
                   2*m5^2)], mp = Sqrt[(2*b*m)/
                (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
                   m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))]}; 
        sols = gensol]]; 
qpC12 = Compile[{{q, _Complex}, {m5, _Complex}, 
         {\[Theta], _Complex}}, Evaluate[qp /. sols[[2]]], 
       RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]; 
qp32 = Re[qpC12[q, m5, \[Theta]]];
```

Then I do NIntegrate:

```
qqq[(q_)?NumericQ, (m5_)?NumericQ] := 
     NIntegrate[(q^2*qp32^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/((2*(2*Pi)^2)*
            Sqrt[-(2*q*Cos[\[Theta]]*qp32) + qp32^2 + q^2]), 
       {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}];
```

And plotting:

```
Plot3D[qqq[q, m5], {q, 0.8, 150}, {m5, 0, 150}]
```

m
It takes about 80 sec and it is a big problem for me because when I use a more complicated function, Mathematica solves it about 3 hours.

Comment: use `NDSolve` https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104553/2079  your approach has to compute the numerical integration for every point

Comment: fyi you should right click and convert your cell to input form before copy paste..

Comment: @agentp the method from your link doesn't work for a function of several variables, is it?

Comment: @agentp And I don't understand about a cell, I did by the rules "indent code by 4 spaces".

Comment: I mean before you copy from mathematica, right click  on the bracket to the right of the cell and convert to input form. (note none of the "copy as" options seem to work properly).  That will get rid of all the `RowBox` garbage that makes your post near impossible to read.

Comment: @agentp Input form before copy paste is done. Thank you!